# How to get frequency of Unicode strings in file

Tags: python, unicode

This is my code to

count  number of times a word occurred in a file( All entries are in Unicode)

```
Text_file  = open("Mytext.txt", 'r').read()

Wordlist = {'മാന്നാര്‍':[], 'മാന്‍':[]}
for line in Text_file:
    for word in Wordlist.keys():
        Wordlist[word].append(line.count(word))
```

My expected result is

```
'മാന്നാര്‍' _ 5
മാന്‍ _ 1
```

My_text  =

```
കുരുവികളോട്‌ കൂട്ട്‌ കൂടാന്‍ …  മട്ടാഞ്ചേരി  കുരുവികളോടൊത്ത്‌ കൂട്ടുകൂടാനും സംരക്ഷിക്കുവാനും കുരുന്നുമനസ്സുകളില്‍ ബോധമുണര്‍ത്താന്‍ ജെയിന്‍ ഫൗണ്ടേഷന്‍ രംഗത്ത്‌  ലോക കുരുവി ദിനമായ ഇന്നലെ കുരുന്നുകള്‍ക്ക്‌ കുരുവിക്കൂടും കുടിവെള്ളപാത്രവും നല്‍കിക്കൊണ്ടാണ്‌ ഫൗണ്ടേഷന്‍ പക്ഷി-മൃഗാദി പരിശീലന പദ്ധതി നടപ്പിലാക്കുന്നത്‌  സ്ക്കൂളുകള്‍  ലൈബ്രറികള്‍ എന്നിവ കേന്ദ്രീകരിച്ചാണ്‌ ഫൗണ്ടേഷന്‍ പദ്ധതി നടപ്പിലാക്കുന്നത്‌  കുരുവികളെ സംരക്ഷിക്കുന്നതിനും  പരിചരിക്കുന്നതിനുമായി പരിസ്ഥിതി സൗഹൃദമായ മണ്‍കുടങ്ങളാണ്‌ ഫൗണ്ടേഷന്‍ സമ്മാനിച്ചത്‌  വേനല്‍കാല ചൂടില്‍ ദാഹമകറ്റുന്നതിന്‌ മണ്‍കലങ്ങളും ഇതിനോടൊപ്പം നല്‍കുകയും ചെയ്തു   
ലോകകുരുവി ദിനത്തില്‍ നടന്ന കുരുവികള്‍ക്ക്‌ കൂടൊരുക്കാം പരിപാടിയില്‍ വിദേശികളും സ്വദേശികളും സാക്ഷികളായി  ഫോര്‍ട്ടുകൊച്ചിയിലെ സെന്റ്‌ മാര്‍ക്കസ്‌ സ്ക്കൂളിലെ കുട്ടികള്‍ക്കാണ്‌ ഫൗണ്ടേഷന്‍ കുരുവിക്കൂടുകള്‍ നല്‍കിയത്‌  ജൈന്‍ ഫൗണ്ടേഷന്‍  ജനമൈത്രി പോലീസ്‌  സെന്റ്മാര്‍ക്കസ്‌ സ്ക്കൂള്‍ എന്നിവരുമായി കൈകോര്‍ത്ത്‌ സംഘടിപ്പിച്ച പരിപാടിയില്‍ ജനമൈത്രി പോലീസ്‌ സി ആര്‍ ഒ  പി യു ഹരിദാസ്‌ സ്ക്കൂള്‍ പ്രിന്‍സിപ്പല്‍ ഹേറിന്‍ ഫെര്‍ണാണ്ടസിന്‌ നല്‍കി പദ്ധതി ഉദ്ഘാടനം ചെയ്തു  ഫൗണ്ടേഷന്‍ ഭാരവാഹി മുകേഷ്‌ ജെയിന്‍ ശാന്തി മേനോന്‍  പ്രിയ കെനറ്റ്‌  എം എം സലീം സുധി എന്നിവര്‍ സംസാരിച്ചു
```

But I am getting

```
{'\xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'മാന്‍': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

What is the error here ?

Comment: You are not using Unicode. You are using byte strings, encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: And you are appending the counts to a list, instead of incrementing the count for a particular word.

Comment: ... and you're iterating over a string, which means `line` will be bound to the individual characters.

Comment: You are making several mistakes, not least to assume that your input file is using the same encoding as your Python source code.

Comment: My file is Unicode encoded I am sure

Comment: "Unicode encoded" doesn't mean anything. I suggest you read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

You need your script file to be unicode, and you need python to open the input file as unicode, utf-8, utf-16 - whatever is the encoding of your file. For example,

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('Mytext.txt', encoding='utf-16')
for line in f:
    print repr(line)
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Apart from that you need your dictionary to map the counted strings to the count, not to a list, as in,

```
Wordlist = {'മാന്നാര്‍':0, 'മാന്‍':0}
```

When you need to increment the dictionary entry:

```
Wordlist['മാന്നാര്‍'] += 1
```

Comment: file opening is not a problem for me   the problem is how to the frequency of words